# nginx not setting cookie with Secure and SameSite

Tags: nginx, cookies

Using nginx to set a cookie but it's not being set correctly. Wondering if there is a mistake in my syntax

```
  location /cdncachecookie {
    # check whether there is a 'useCdnCache=true|false' key/value pair.
    if ($query_string ~ "^useCdnCache=(true|false)$") {
      add_header Set-Cookie "useCdnCache=$1;Domain=company.com;Path=/;Max-Age=3600;SameSite=None;Secure=true";
      return 200 "";
    }
    return 403;
  }
```

The cookie I'm getting doesn't have any indication of SameSite or Secure.